# summary statistics when group is not NA

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I would like to calculate the weight and height summary statistics (mean, range) for group 1, group 2 and group 3. I am specifically looking for a way to do this by calculating summary stats when group 1 is not NA (to calc group 1)
And the same for group 2, when the column is not NA.

In the example below, the weight for group 1 would be 3,2 and for group 2 would be 3,5

```
dt <- tibble(
  group1 = c(1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA),
  group2 = c(NA, NA, 2, 2, NA, NA),
  group3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 3, 3),
  weight = c(3, 2, 3, 5, NA, 7),
  height = c(10, NA, 14, 15, 11, 20)
)
```

Comment: How does your expected output look like?

Comment: I am quite sure that Martin Gal's answer is correct. I get the same result. Otherwise the question needs clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dt %>% 
  group_by(group = coalesce(group1, group2, group3)) %>% 
  summarize(
    mean_weight = mean(weight, na.rm = TRUE),
    mean_height = mean(height, na.rm = TRUE)
    )
```

which returns

```r
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  group mean_weight mean_height
  <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
1     1         2.5        10  
2     2         4          14.5
3     3         7          15.5
```

If there are multiple groups per row, you could use

```r
dt %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    starts_with("group"),
    values_drop_na = TRUE,
    values_to = "group"
    ) %>%
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarize(
    mean_weight = mean(weight, na.rm = TRUE),
    mean_height = mean(height, na.rm = TRUE)
  )
```

which returns basically the same

```r
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  group mean_weight mean_height
  <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
1     1         2.5        10  
2     2         4          14.5
3     3         7          15.5
```

How does this work?

1. First we bring the data into a "long" format using `pivot_longer`. We take every column starting with "group" (`starts_with("group")`). Those column names go into the new column `name` (default name, you can change it with `names_to = "YourNewColumnNameHere"`). The values are put into the new column `group` using `values_to = "group"`. If you don't use this argument, the values are stored in the column `value` by default. The `values_drop_na = TRUE` takes care of every cell containing an `NA` value. These are removed.
   So after using `pivot_longer` the transformed data looks like

```r
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  weight height name   group
   <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>
1      3     10 group1     1
2      2     NA group1     1
3      3     14 group2     2
4      5     15 group2     2
5     NA     11 group3     3
6      7     20 group3     3
```

2. Next we `group_by(group)` so the next transformations are applied to each independent group and don't affect each other.
3. `summarize` takes the grouping and calculates the new columns for each group. All other columns are dropped. The `na.rm = TRUE` argument of `mean()` takes care of `NA` values: those are ignored. Without this argument, `mean_weight` for group `3` would be `NA`.

**Edit**

Thanks to akruns comment this can be generalized to multiple columns without reshaping by using the big-bang-operator:

```r
dt %>% 
  group_by(group = coalesce(!!! select(., starts_with('group')))) %>% 
  summarise(across(c(weight, height), mean, na.rm = TRUE))
```

akrun uses a more advanced approach:

1. The core of this is the complex `group_by` statement.
2. `coalesce()` is a function used to get the first non-`NA`-element in order of the arguments. For example: `coalesce(NA_real_, 1, 2)` returns `1` since this is the first non-`NA`-value. Since `coalesce()` is vectorized, `coalesce(group1, group2, group3)` and your group columns contain only one value per row

```r
dt %>% 
  group_by(group = coalesce(group1, group2, group3))
```

returns an already grouped tibble.

```r
# A tibble: 6 x 6
# Groups:   group [3]
  group1 group2 group3 weight height group
   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1      1     NA     NA      3     10     1
2      1     NA     NA      2     NA     1
3     NA      2     NA      3     14     2
4     NA      2     NA      5     15     2
5     NA     NA      3     NA     11     3
6     NA     NA      3      7     20     3
```

3. If there are many/multiple columns named `"group"`, we don't want to type `coalesce(group1, ... , group100)`. So we are using a function, that selects all those columns. Here `!!! select(., starts_with('group'))` is the best way: Take every column of your data.frame starting with "group". Unfortunately, `select` returns a data.frame (which is a special version of a list of vectors). We need to supply `coalesce` with multiple vectors as arguments. A *list of vectors* won't do the job:

```r
dt %>% 
  group_by(group = coalesce(select(., starts_with('group'))))
```

returns

```r
# Groups:   group [3]
  group1 group2 group3 weight height group$group1 $group2 $group3
   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>        <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1      1     NA     NA      3     10            1      NA      NA
2      1     NA     NA      2     NA            1      NA      NA
3     NA      2     NA      3     14           NA       2      NA
4     NA      2     NA      5     15           NA       2      NA
5     NA     NA      3     NA     11           NA      NA       3
6     NA     NA      3      7     20           NA      NA       3
```

which isn't what we are looking for. The big-bang-operator `!!!` separates this *list of vectors* into multiple single vectors that are given to `coalesce` as arguments. So

```r
dt %>% 
  group_by(group = coalesce(!!! select(., starts_with('group'))))
```

returns

```r
# A tibble: 6 x 6
# Groups:   group [3]
  group1 group2 group3 weight height group
   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1      1     NA     NA      3     10     1
2      1     NA     NA      2     NA     1
3     NA      2     NA      3     14     2
4     NA      2     NA      5     15     2
5     NA     NA      3     NA     11     3
6     NA     NA      3      7     20     3
```

4. So now we have a grouped data.frame/tibble and we can apply the `summarise` function: `summarise(across(c(weight, height), mean, na.rm = TRUE))`. `across()` tells `summarise` to apply the function `mean` with argument `na.rm = TRUE` to the columns `weight` and `height`. That's a more elegant version of

```r
summarize(
    mean_weight = mean(weight, na.rm = TRUE),
    mean_height = mean(height, na.rm = TRUE)
    )
```

without the renaming (which also could have been done with `across`).

Comment: I think your answer is correct. I tried up and down and came to the same result. One thing that may be intended is if you change all `NA` with `0`  before the calculation for example with `mutate(across(c(weight, height), ~replace_na(.,0))) %>% ` then the mean value for `group 3` changes to `3.5`.

Comment: I'm not sure about the actual output OP wants. If we don't summarize, the output for group 1 is `c(3, 2)` and for group 2 `c(3, 5)`. For group 3 it could be either `c(NA, 7)` or `7`.

Comment: I think if there are multiple groups, you could also do  wihtout reshaping `dt %>% group_by(group = coalesce(!!! select(., starts_with('group')))) %>% summarise(across(c(weight, height), mean, na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: That's great! I'm still trying to understand how this really works.

Comment: What packages are you using? `plyr`? Perhaps you could use `dplyr::summarise` instead of `summarise`.

Comment: Hi, thanks so much! this works great, provided I prefix everything! Can I ask, what the lines of code are doing? So `group_by` is grouping by the column 'group' 
And then I get a little lost. I need to understand so I can add in range, and be able to do it myself next time :)

Comment: Which one of the three versions did you use?

Comment: I tried all 3, they all worked. Ideally I'd like a little clarity for version 2 ("If there are multiple groups per row, you could use") and version 3 by Akrun

Comment: I'll add some explanation to my answer. :-)

Comment: @Gabriella I added some explanations.

Comment: wow, that is just wonderful! Thank you so very much

Answer (score 2):

An option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dt)[, lapply(.SD, mean, na.rm = TRUE),
        .(group = fcoalesce(group1, group2, group3)),
        .SDcols = c('weight', 'height')]
   group weight height
1:     1    2.5   10.0
2:     2    4.0   14.5
3:     3    7.0   15.5
```

Comment: Thank you for this! My question was not clear enough, so apologies, there are other variables in the DF that I don't want to take into account. In your answer how might I specify I want to look at weight and height?

Comment: @Gabriella in that case, just specify the `.SDcols` (updated)

Comment: Thank you so so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can find summary statistics for each group and then filter the NA out. Take group1 for example.

```
dt %>%
  group_by(group1) %>%
  summarise(mean_weight = mean(weight, na.rm=T),
            mean_height = mean(height, na.rm=T),
            .groups = 'drop') %>%
  filter(!(is.na(group1)))
```

Comment: this gives me an error: 
Error in is.data.frame(x) : 
  'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
In addition: Warning message:
In mean.default(data, na.rm = TRUE) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

Comment: I think you are trying to aggregate some column with `list` items in it. Can you share more details of the columns like `str(dt)`? And which columns you are trying to aggregate.

Comment: Hi, absolutely:
 tibble [6 × 5] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ group1: num [1:6] 1 1 NA NA NA NA
 $ group2: num [1:6] NA NA 2 2 NA NA
 $ group3: num [1:6] NA NA NA NA 3 3
 $ weight: num [1:6] 3 2 3 5 NA 7
 $ height: num [1:6] 10 NA 14 15 11 20